# Unable to install pod 'CalendarKit', '0.1.22' in Swift 3 and Xcode 8.3.3

Tags: ios, swift3, cocoapods, calendarkit

[The GitHub page for CalendarKit](https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarKit) specifies that the setting for Swift 3 is:

```
pod 'CalendarKit', '0.1.22'
```

but that throws an error:

> [!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
>   - `CalendarKit (= 0.1.22)` required by `Podfile`
>   None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `CalendarKit (= 0.1.22)`.
>
> You have either:
>    * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The information they provided is incorrect, their Podspec is not up to date. You should specify the git and the [commit for 0.1.22](https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarKit/releases/tag/0.1.22) in your Podfile to download `CalendarKit` for Swift 3:

```
pod 'CalendarKit', :git => 'https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarKit.git', :commit => '65ace5a'
```

Answer (score 1):

Could you try `pod repo update` and see if this helps?

Another user had [a similar problem](https://github.com/richardtop/CalendarKit/issues/103) and updating the CocoaPods specs repository helped them.

Here is the relevant [podspec](https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs/blob/master/Specs/e/6/6/CalendarKit/0.1.22/CalendarKit.podspec.json) to the corresponding version, so it is not the problem in the Specs repository itself.

Disclosure: I am the author of the CalendarKit